# Deciding whether a context-free grammar's language is empty

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, decision-problem

Consider the formal problem:

> Given a context-free grammar $G$, is the language $L(G)$ empty?

Can we determine if the problem is recursively enumerable, recursive, in NP, or in P? Can the entire procedure be explained?

Comment: Please ask 1 question and pose it in the title. This makes your question far more useful for those who will come after us. Thanks.

Comment: Also, what research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here, to make sure your question isn't already covered in standard sources -- I suggest checking textbooks and searching online (e.g., Wikipedia).  In this case, your question is answered on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Decidable_problems) with a reference, and it's covered in standard textbooks.